# WSO2 ESB webservice load balance

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there a way for distributing services requests among different servers? The ideia is high avaiability for a webservice, controlled by wso2 esb. I'll have same service deployed in more then one server(jboss) and I intend wso2 handle this.
The option 'pinned servers', when creating custom proxy, can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Pinned server" attribute controls the Proxy service deployment in Several servers. Sometimes We need to use a one CAPP file to deploy artifacts in several servers, but may require to deploy a proxy service artifact in Selected servers. So in this case "Pinned server" attribute can be used.

You can give a list of Synapse server names, where this Proxy Service should be deployed using pinnedServers attribute. It takes the server names separated by comma or space character. If there is no pinned server list, then the Proxy Service will be started in all server instances.

If a pinned server names list is given, it will only start in the given named Synapse server instances.

For your question "**Is there a way for distributing services reuests among different servers?**"

You can achieve this using a cluster setup with a Loadbalancers like nginex, httpd.

[httpd](http://shafreenanfar.blogspot.com/2015/03/minimum-steps-to-load-balance-wso2-esb.html)
[nginx](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+ESB+4.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use pinned server option, you can add a property called pinnedServers property in proxy like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="myproxy"
       transports="https,http"
       pinnedServers="server1"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://www.google.com"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

In here "server1" is synapse server name where this Proxy Service should be deployed using pinnedServers attribute.
Next you need to add synapse server instance name as following in axis2.xml according to above proxy

```
<parameter name="SynapseConfig.ServerName" locked="false">server1</parameter>
```

You need to restart the ESB to get the effect from the pinnedServers property.

Then you need to give the name to a Synapse server instance by specifying *-DSynapseServerName=* property when you execute the startup script, wso2server.bat or wso2server.sh

Please refer [1] as a reference of setting the pinnedServers property in proxy.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB403/Proxy+Services